How to Deploy Nextjs 14.2.4 in cPanel ? with Application mode = production
When I deploy my app on cPanel, the code is successfully deployed in development mode. However, after some time, I encounter a 404 error in the network tab indicating that certain chunk and CSS files are not loading.
I want to deploy the app in production mode
I tried creating a server.js file:
server.js
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || "3000", 10);
const dev = process.env.NEXT_APP_NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }).listen(port);

  console.log(
    `> Server listening at http://localhost:${port} in ${
      dev ? "development" : process.env.NEXT_APP_NODE_ENV
    } mode`
  );
});

Package.json

"scripts": {
"dev": "node server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "node server.js"
},

I tried this setup, and I also changed the configuration file from next.config.js to next.config.mjs because I was getting an error during npm run build when importing a package in the server file.

